# Unable to update the textview in the list in gridview android

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview

I have a database and `gridview` list, my `gridview` will read the database and display all the rows in the grid. In my `griditem` I have a `textview.` the text in the `textview` of the latest item is not updated correctly. However if I add new item to the `database`, the text in the `griditem` is not updated.

I did this

```
    result = db.getAllresult;
    adapter.updateResults(result);
```

and in the adapter,

```
public void updateResults(List<Object> results) {
        this.list = results;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The size of the `gridlist` increase, but the text attached to the new added item is not updated correctly. Anyone know?

Comment: Can you paste your adapter code here?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
 result = db.getAllresult;
```

with

```
 result.addAll(db.getAllresult);
```

then

```
  adapter.notifySetDataChanged();
```

Comment: It doesnt really work, my gridview can display 6 items in one view, as it creates the 7th item it will create the scroll. however the 7th item is the same as the first item. I checked my db i am getting correct value, but I dont know why the 7th item will show the text of the 1st item

Comment: Hi I found out the problem is the gridview position reset to 0 if it requires scrolling, do you know how to solve this?

Comment: can you post your code which is in getView() method

Answer (score 0):

you can use adapter.notifySetDataChanged() after you set value to adapter for listview